no puedo cargar mi archivo sql en las pruebas de spring boot
al intentar cargar un archivo sql para ingresar datos en las pruebas de spring, me sale un error indicando que la clase no existe

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TIPO_GENERO" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into tipo_genero (id_genero,genero) values (1,'hombre') [42104-214]

así esta el archivo sql, se están usando exactamente los mismos nombres que especifique en las entidades del main
insert into tipo_genero (id_genero,genero) values (1,'hombre');

asi esta mi .properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver 
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
pero cuando borro el archivo sql, en mi debug se muestra como si se crean las tablas y todo funciona
2024-05-04T13:11:12.128-05:00 DEBUG 23132 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table detalle_producto (
        id_detalle_producto integer generated by default as identity,
        cantidad_producto integer not null,
        descripcion_producto varchar(255) not null,
        precio_producto float(53) not null,
        primary key (id_detalle_producto)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table detalle_producto (
        id_detalle_producto integer generated by default as identity,
        cantidad_producto integer not null,
        descripcion_producto varchar(255) not null,
        precio_producto float(53) not null,
        primary key (id_detalle_producto)
    )
2024-05-04T13:11:12.139-05:00 DEBUG 23132 --- [ main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    create table empleado (
        id_empleado integer generated by default as identity,
        cedula_empleado varchar(10) not null,
        email_empleado varchar(40) not null,
        nombre_empleado varchar(20) not null,
        password_empleado varchar(100) not null,
        telefono_empleado varchar(10),
        tipo_empleado varchar(255) not null check (tipo_empleado in ('EMPLEADO','JEFE')),
        primary key (id_empleado)
    )

mi problema por lo que veo es que al agregar un archivo sql. spring intenta sacar el ddl de ahi, pero ese archivo no esta destinado para eso, como puedo especificarle esto a spring

Hay algunas convenciones que debes de seguir apra que funcione.

Tu script de sql se debe de llamar data.sql
debes agregas a tu properties spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

El archivo data.sql debe de estar en tus carpetas de testing para que se lo detecte y lo cargue en el classpath, si deseas usar una ubicación específica para tu archivo lo puedes hacer en tu properties con la entrada spring.sql.init.data-locations.
Si tienes alguna duda puedes consultar la documentación oficial al respecto.
Si quieres un tutorial de como cargar el esquema de la base de datos y los datos desde scripts sql puedes seguir este tutorial.

muchas gracias, al agregar "spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true" al properties si me creo primero las tablas y luego cargo los datos, te lo agradezo mucho

@sebastiangarciaalzate entonces te recomiendo aceptar la respuesta al darle click al botón de palomita verde que aparece a la izquierda de esta respuesta para que sea más fácil de hallar para otros con el mismo problema. Saludos.
